# How to define multiple initialization parameters for DataTable?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have the following js code to initialize a DataTable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

What I'm currently failing to figure out is, how do I now define further settings other than the buttons as an additional argument? I would for example like to define the settings of the length menu such as is explained here https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    } );
} );
```

So I'd do something like this, which doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

This is likely obvious, but I'm just starting out with js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add letter `l` in `dom`

Something like this:

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ]
});
```

You can check the reference in: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

**Result** : https://jsfiddle.net/g2kdfrcu/